# How to pass modify CGAL's Point Value?

Tags: c++, computer-vision, cgal

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel     Kernel;
typedef Reconstruction::Point                                         Point;
typedef CGAL::Point_set_3<Point>                                Point_set;
```

I declaration Point_set in cgal. but i donot know how to change value of it, because the Point_set return value is alway const

```
  Point_set pts;
   pts.point(i).x()=123;//cause error
   pts.point(i)=Point(1,2,3);//also raise error
```

Comment: Looking in the code I see: `Point& point (const Index& index) { return m_points[index]; }`. Are you sure you are using the same point type and that `Point_set` is not const?

Comment: `Point &  point (const Index &index)
  Returns a reference to the point corresponding to index. 
 
const Point &  point (const Index &index) const
  Returns a constant reference to the point corresponding to index. ` THX  !  but it overload the function ,I have no idea how to call the first func

Comment: @Snail the first function is called by default unless the Point_set is const. There is a good reason why this website has a policy of asking for a [mcve], please follow the rules...